# Unexpected token. state = {} when running jest

Tags: react-native, jestjs, expo

Hey guys i'm running into

```
      simplifica/App.jsx: Unexpected token (17:8)
        15 | 
        16 | export default class App extends React.Component {
      > 17 |   state = {
           |         ^
        18 |     isLoadingComplete: false
        19 |   };
        20 |
```

When running jest, i am hours in this, i have found a few problems like mine but the solutions didn't work for me, neither using @babel/plugin-proposal-classproperties

Here is my `babel.config.js`

```
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo', 'module:react-native-dotenv'],
    plugins: [
      [
        '@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators',
        {
          legacy: true
        }
      ],
      ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties', { loose: true }]
    ]
  };
};
```

And here is my `jest config`

```
   "jest": {
      "preset": "jest-expo",
      "transformIgnorePatterns": [
        "node_modules/(?!((jest-)?react-native|react-clone-referenced-element|expo(nent)?|@expo(nent)?/.*|react-navigation|@react-navigation/.*|sentry-expo|native-base))"
      ],
      "moduleFileExtensions": [
        "js",
        "jsx"
      ],
      "transform": {
        "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest",
        "^.+\\.jsx$": "babel-jest",
        ".*": "<rootDir>/node_modules/webpack-babel-jest"
      }
    }
```

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it! For anyone having the same issue:

1. Make sure your jest and babel-jest are in compatible releases
2. Make sure to use Babel 7
3. My transform was also wrong, these 2 lines:

```
"^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest",
        "^.+\\.jsx$": "babel-jest",
```

Should be only one, like this:

```
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx|ts)$": "babel-jest"
```